# Issue with reading nodes and its elements using XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document like as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Projects>
  <Project>
        <ProjectNo>111</ProjectNo>
        <Client/>
        <Responsible/>
        <Participants/>
        <Date>13-11-2015</Date>
  </Project>
  <Transfers ID="1">
        <SampleID>1</SampleID>
        <SampleNo>222</SampleNo>
        <ChamberNo>p111</ChamberNo>
  </Transfers>
  <Transfers ID="2">
        <SampleID>2</SampleID>
        <SampleNo>32</SampleNo>
        <ChamberNo>p311</ChamberNo>
  </Transfers>
  <Transfers ID="3">
        <SampleID>3</SampleID>
        <SampleNo>42</SampleNo>
        <ChamberNo>p211</ChamberNo>
  </Transfers>
</Projects>
```

I am trying to read nodes and its elements like this

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(GlobalVariables.XmlPath + "\\"  + GlobalVariables.ProjectID + ".xml");

var project = from p in xmlDocument.Descendants("Project")
              select new Project
              {

                  ProjectNo = p.Element("ProjectNo").Value,
                  Client = p.Element("Client").Value,                       
                  ProjectResponsible = p.Element("Responsible").Value,
                  Participants = p.Element("Participants").Value,
                  Date = Convert.ToDateTime(p.Element("Date").Value).Date,
              };

var Samples = (from s in xmlDocument.Descendants("Transfers")
               select new Sample
               {

                   SampleID = Convert.ToInt32(s.Element("SampleID").Value),
                   SampleNo = s.Element("SampleNo").Value,
                   ChamberNo = s.Element("ChamberNo").Value,
               }

              );
int SamplesNo = Samples.Count();

CreateWordDocument(project, Samples, SamplesNo);
```

I am able to read nodes and its elements at first time but if i edit values in xml file and try to read again then i am getting error "NullreferenceException was unhandled" Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What might be the problem and how to rectify it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the edit?  Are you removing nodes?

Comment: My *guess* is that you modified an element name so it was no longer found. We can't say for sure though as we don't know what the modification was, and you haven't even provided us the stack trace. We really need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: I am editing only elements like sample no and saving.